# Help using epos_hardware

Tags: ros, controller-manager, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!
I am trying to add 4 maxon motors controlled by 4 maxon drives (EPOS2 70/10) and I have been unsuccessful so far. I have communicated with the EPOS2 in Windows and have gone through the initial setup correctly. *EDIT: I will summarize the post in order to make it easier to read.*

At first I had some USB permission problem which was solved by giving the device special permissions in `udev/rules.d`. I thought that was not enough and made this post but as *ahendrix* pointed out probably only by rebooting my computer did the permission change take effect.

I am still trying to make the example work with my own EPOS2 + Motor and the following issue still puzzles me: I have edited the example.yaml file that came with the epos_hardware to fit my motor. Still when I run the example.launch file I get:

```
[ERROR] [1440402458.067846767]: Could not find motor
[ERROR] [1440402458.067882353]: Could not configure motor: my_joint_actuator
[FATAL] [1440402458.067895978]: Failed to initialize motors
```

I realized something trying to troubleshoot the problem. My device's serial number is:

```
Serial Number: 0x662080006193
```

The package documentation states:

> ~/motor_name/serial_number (string)

> The serial number of the motor (in hex). This is used to locate the motor.

So I have introduced: **serial_number: '662080006193'**. No problems so far but whenever I try to run the example and check rqt_console I get this ROS_INFO message:

```
Initializing: 0x7461757463416e6f
```

Which could be the cause of the problem since to my understanding it is trying to connect to a different device (correct me if I'm wrong). I have tried introducing the number in a variety of ways but I either got the same number (0x7461757463416e6f) or zero (0x0). Does anybody have any clues as to what's happening behind the curtain? Is the number being converted to hex twice? I have tried introducing the decimal equivalent but then I get zero in rqt_console...

Now the latest update I have is I have tried running roswtf with epos_hardware's example.launch file and this is what I get:

```
ERROR The following packages have rpath issues in manifest.xml:
 * epos_hardware: found flag "-L/opt/ros/indigo/share/controller_manager/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/indigo/share/controller_manager/lib"
 * controller_manager: found flag "-L/opt/ros/indigo/share/controller_manager/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/indigo/share/controller_manager/lib"
```

Could this be the source of the problem or at least a part of it? How do I fix it? I have checked package.xml in both epos_hardware and controller_manager but I am not exactly sure about what to do. I have tried commenting the following line in controller_manager's package.xml but although roswtf gave me no errors I still get the same problem when I try to execute the example:

```
  <export>
    <cpp lflags="-L${prefix}/lib -lcontroller_manager" cflags="-I${prefix}/include"/>
  </export>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216315/help-using-epos_hardware/) by [maztentropy](https://answers.ros.org/users/22392/maztentropy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-08-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I sort of made it work for now. As I initially suspected the problem was in the way the serial number is handled internally. I manually changed the file "epos.cpp" and recompiled and the issue was solved. This is the change I did in case anyone is interested:

```
   if(!config_nh_.getParam("serial_number", serial_number_str)) {
     ROS_ERROR("You must specify a serial number");
     valid_ = false;
  }
  else {
    
    ROS_ASSERT(SerialNumberFromHex(serial_number_str, &serial_number_));
  }
```

I changed it to:

```
config_nh_.getParam("serial_number", serial_number_str);
ROS_ASSERT(SerialNumberFromHex(serial_number_str, &serial_number_));
```

I think that serial_number_str was not being collected properly but I am no expert. How can I make it known to the author?

---

Originally posted by [maztentropy](https://answers.ros.org/users/22392/maztentropy/) with karma: 35 on 2015-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-08-31**:
According to the docs the serial nr should be specified in hex, as you had found out. Have you tried setting the parameter to `0x662080006193` (if that is your serial nr in hex)?

As to how to contact the author, use the issue tracker at https://github.com/RIVeR-Lab/epos_hardware.

**Comment by [maztentropy](https://answers.ros.org/users/22392/maztentropy/) on 2015-08-31**:
I did try that form also, but in the example provided in the package is was entered as '662080006193' that's why I have used it for the post. Thanks for your interest anyway.

**Comment by [mitchell](https://answers.ros.org/users/23748/mitchell/) on 2015-09-02**:
The serial number you have is probably in decimal. Try converting it to hex with the 0x prefix and see if that works. Feel free to add a PR to support both formats of SN. Not sure about the controller_manager issue, but I would try filing a bug against controller_manager

**Comment by [maztentropy](https://answers.ros.org/users/22392/maztentropy/) on 2015-09-03**:
I used the serial number obtained from "list_devices" (which I think is already hex). I have anyway tried different ways of inputting the number and none of them worked. The ROS_INFO message which parses the device you're connecting to kept saying "0x7461757463416e6f" or "0x0".

**Comment by [jdeleon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27207/jdeleon/) on 2016-06-17**:
@maztentropy did you finally get the EPOS work? I'm having the same 3 errors as you.

**Comment by [johnyang](https://answers.ros.org/users/26493/johnyang/) on 2017-09-13**:
I'm running into the same problem here now. However, the exact same code works on a computer running Ubuntu14.04 but failed on another machine running Ubuntu 14.02. If I removed ROS_ASSERT, then it works fine. Any explanation to his?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't have any experience with the epos driver, but this looks like a fairly standard permissions problem.

The general things to do are:

- Examine the permissions on /dev/bus/usb/003/007 with `ls -l /dev/bus/usb/003/007`
- Manually grant permissions to all users for this device: `sudo chmod 777 /dev/bus/usb/003/007`
- Confirm that the permissions are now set to read/write for all users: `ls -l /dev/bus/usb/003/007`
- Try your node again now that the permissions are less restrictive: `rosrun epos_hardware list_devices`

If those steps work, then you've confirmed that the permissions are the issue, and you can work on setting up a udev rule to set the permissions correctly in the future.

If those steps don't work, update your question with the output from each command, and I'll help you troubleshoot further.

**UPDATE**

I suspect that the udev rules you attempted to set up on your first attempt were correct, but they weren't loaded properly until you rebooted; hence why your permissions issue is "magically" gone.

I can't help you with the epos driver itself (no experience there), but the errors suggest that you should carefully check that the names in all of your config files match.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-08-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bigcmos](https://answers.ros.org/users/20129/bigcmos/) on 2016-02-04**:
FYI, You can install the udev rules with this command: `rosrun epos_hardware install_udev_rules`